# How does biblatex check for equal annotator, introduction's author, etc.?

Tags: biblatex

Biblatex is able to check whether a name appears in different fields and is able to adapt the reference showed. For instance, if translation and annotations are made by the same person, biblatex creates a reference which unifies both data with a string such as `Trans. and annot. by [person X]`. If I am not wrong this is achieved inside the bibmacro `translator+othersstrg` (defined in biblatex.def) using the macro `ifnamesequal` which checks for two names being equal.

Unfortunately in case of equal fields `annotator` and `introduction` no check is made. How could I achieve that biblatex does not show the name Michel García twice in the following MWE? I.e. How to force biblatex to check for these two fields being equal?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{stack.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{repertorio1972}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And this is the bibliographical entry:

```
@Book{repertorio1972,
title =        {Repertorio de príncipes de España},
year =         1972,
annotator =    {García, Michel},
introduction = {García, Michel},
publisher =    {CSIC},
location =     {Jaén}
}
```

Comment: Note that if you add this person as either an editor or a translator too, then the relevant collapsing does occur.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: thanks. You're right. But if I load `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` the output is different as in English. The editor is put before the title and then the name is set twice.

Comment: That is also the english behaviour if the same person is the author instead.  I haven't yet been able to deduce how biblatex works with this.  The release notes, refer to `biblatex.def` and the `lbx` files, and note that it is not easy to explain how the mechanism works!

Comment: @AndrewSwann: yes, I am also trying to understand how biblatex works with all these drivers, macros, and so on. It is very rich and powerful.

Answer (score 3):

These checks are indeed done via bibliography macros. Combined strings are defined in the localization modules (`lbx` files). The default definitions are demonstrative rather than exhaustive; they don't account for all types of overlap in authors of annotations, introductions, commentaries, forewards and afterwords. However you can modify the relevant macros from `biblatex.def` to achieve the output you want. For example:

```
\NewBibliographyString{withannotatorin}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  withannotatorin = {with annots\adddot and intro\adddot}}

\newbibmacro*{withannotatorin}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifnameundef{annotator}} or test {\ifnameundef{introduction}}
    or not test {\ifnamesequal{annotator}{introduction}} }
    {}
    {\bibstring{withannotatorin}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[withannotator]{annotator}%
     \clearname{annotator}%
     \clearname{introduction}}}

\renewbibmacro*{withothers}{%
  \usebibmacro{withcommentator}%
  \clearname{commentator}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{withannotatorin}%
  \usebibmacro{withannotator}%
  \clearname{annotator}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{withintroduction}%
  \clearname{introduction}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{withforeword}%
  \clearname{foreword}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{withafterword}%
  \clearname{afterword}}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. This is working. I think I will analyze thoroughly the file biblatex.def in the next days.